# Trying to create a wordcloud of a specific column

Tags: python, word-cloud

Trying to create a word cloud in my dataframe "coffee_df" of the "reviews" column and Polarity column that only shows the reviews when Polarity > 0.5

There are no specific shapes or size preferences I need to account for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how your dataframe was created or what it has so i created a dummy data frame just to show how to create a wordcloud of the reviews with Polarity > 0.5. Here is the code:

```
# importing all necessary modules
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud

# Create dummy data frame
reviews = ["I Love This!", "This coffee is the best", "I need more of this"]
polarity = [0.3, 0.6, 0.7]
data = {"reviews": reviews, "Polarity": polarity}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

# filter data frame by Polarity > 0.5
filtered_df = df[df["Polarity"] > 0.5]

# create single string from reviews column
text = filtered_df.reviews.str.cat(sep=' ')

# create word cloud
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(text)
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

And here is the output:

[image]